# Java Generics and templates

Tags: java, templates, generics, types, wildcard

I have the following `Java` class definition:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

static public void copyTo(Iterator<? extends Number> it, List<? extends Number> out) {
    while(it.hasNext())
        out.add(it.next());
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> in = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        in.add(i);
    }
    Iterator<Integer> it = in.iterator();
    List<Number> out = new ArrayList<Number>();
    copyTo(it, out);
    System.out.println(out.size());
}
```

}

That's it, I define the method `copyTo` using `wildcards` in `Java`. I define `List<Number> out` but `Iterator<Integer> it`. My thinking is I can define the iterator as `Iterator<? extends Number>` and that would type match. However that's not the case:

```
Test.java:13: error: no suitable method found for add(Number)
            out.add(it.next());
               ^
    method List.add(int,CAP#1) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method List.add(CAP#1) is not applicable
      (actual argument Number cannot be converted to CAP#1 by method invocation conversion)
    method Collection.add(CAP#1) is not applicable
      (actual argument Number cannot be converted to CAP#1 by method invocation conversion)
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Number from capture of ? extends Number
1 error
```

So I went ahead and I defined yet another definition for the `copyTo` method:

```
static public void copyTo(Iterator<? super Integer> it, List<? super Integer> out) {
        while(it.hasNext())
            out.add(it.next());
    }
```

It doesn't work either. What would be the correct say of using `wildcards` in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you want to impose a constraint by adding a type variable to the method itself since by using wildcards you can't impose a constraint between the two arguments, then you must thing about variance of the types involved in your method:

- you want as an input an `Iterator<X>` where `X` is at least the type of the numeric type you want to copy (or a subtype)
- you want as output a List where `Y` is at most the type of the numeric type (or a super type)

These constraints are different and must be expressed differently:

```
static public <T> void copyTo(Iterator<? extends T> it, List<? super T> out) {
while(it.hasNext())
    out.add(it.next());
}
```

Which is basically "I accept an `Iterator` of `T` or a subtype of `T` and I output to a List of `T` or a supertype of `T`"

Answer (score 2):

If a method signature involves two or more wildcards, and the logic of your method requires them to be the same, you need to use a generic type parameter instead of wildcards.

```
static public <T extends Number> void copyTo(Iterator<? extends T> it, List<? super T> out) {
    while(it.hasNext())
        out.add(it.next());
}
```

Here I have used PECS (producer extends, consumer super). `out` is consuming `T`s (so `super`), whereas the iterator is producing `T`s, so `extends`.

**EDIT**

As @Cinnam correctly points out in the comments, you can get away with

```
static void copyTo(Iterator<? extends Integer> it, List<? super Integer> out)
```

These signatures are effectively equivalent because `Integer` is final, so any class that is a super class of some class extending `Integer` must be a super class of `Integer`.

However, the two signatures are not equivalent as far as the compiler is concerned. You can test this by trying

```
static <T extends Number> void copyTo1(Iterator<? extends T> it, List<? super T> out) {
    copyTo2(it, out); // doesn't compile
}

static void copyTo2(Iterator<? extends Integer> it, List<? super Integer> out) {
   copyTo1(it, out);
}
```

This does *not* compile, showing that as far as the compiler is concerned, the version with the type parameter is more general.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough if it was `void copyTo(Iterator<? extends Integer> it, List<? super Integer> out)` ?

Comment: @Cinnam Yes, you're right. That's a better solution.